# On button click, hide elements and display the one I need

Tags: javascript

Whenever I click on the first button, I want to hide rest of elements and display the title with description for first item, I want to do this for the rest items as well. Whenever I am trying to do this, I am not able to target all elements in my function. Can someone assist? Also should I add to the buttons something like `data-*` and based on that display/show the div?

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
       this.items = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
       this.btn = document.querySelector('.click');
       console.log(this.items); //logs elements
       this.btn.addEventListener("click", this.testFunc);
 }
 
 testFunc() {
  console.log(this.items); //undefined ?
 }
}

new MyClass();
```

```css
.test {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item first">
  <h3>Item-1</h3>
  <p class="test">
    dadwa dwao dawkda
  </p>
</div>

<div class="item second">
  <h3>Item-1</h3>
  <p class="test">
    dadwa dwao dawkda
  </p>
</div>
<div class="item third">
  <h3>Item-1</h3>
  <p class="test">
    dadwa dwao dawkda
  </p>
</div>


<button class="click">
  Test
</button>

<button class="click">
  Test
</button>

<button class="click">
  Test
</button>
```

Comment: `this.btn.addEventListener("click", this.testFunc.bind(this));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following update to your `MyClass` should do the trick.

The main change is that you attach an event listenter to *all* buttons (changed `querySelector('.click')` to `querySelectorAll('.click')`.  And the helper function `showItem` takes an index which is which item to show (and hide all the rest).

I'm using the `hidden` attribute to show/hide elements.  You could instead add or remove a class from the item that has the `display: none`.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.items = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
    this.btns = document.querySelectorAll(".click");

    this.items.forEach((item, index) => {
      item.setAttribute("hidden", true);
      this.btns
        .item(index)
        .addEventListener("click", (ev) => this.showItem(index));
    });
  }

  showItem(idx) {
    this.items.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (index === idx) {
        item.removeAttribute("hidden");
      } else {
        item.setAttribute("hidden", true);
      }
    });
  }
}

new MyClass();
```

```html
<div class="item first">
  <h3>Item-1</h3>
  <p class="test">
    dadwa dwao dawkda
  </p>
</div>

<div class="item second">
  <h3>Item-2</h3>
  <p class="test">
    dadwa dwao dawkda
  </p>
</div>
<div class="item third">
  <h3>Item-3</h3>
  <p class="test">
    dadwa dwao dawkda
  </p>
</div>


<button class="click">
  Test 1
</button>

<button class="click">
  Test 2
</button>

<button class="click">
  Test 3
</button>
```